# Changing the Data-caption of image in jquery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Hi friends i am trying to change the Data-caption of a in dynamic mode.

```
$("#btnchange").click(function(){
    var newanchor=  $(".fancybox a");
    newanchor.attr('caption', 'i am new caption');
});
```

When I clicked on the image to open it in third party plugin, tool called(fancybox), it's caption is not displaying.

But when I tried to add data caption by default it like:

```
<a id='a1' class="fancybox" data-caption='hey' 
 href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7171/6417719753_374653e28c_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7171/6417719753_374653e28c_m.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
```

Then it is showing perfectly. See my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RyTcS/401/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`,

```
newanchor.data('caption', 'i am new caption');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RyTcS/403/)

And as well as your selector should be `.fancybox` instead of `.fancybox a`

Comment: changing to data is working fine...but i have seen so many examples to change data attributes by keyword 'attr' only thats why i am trying wid dat

Comment: `newanchor.attr('caption'` is not equal to `newanchor.attr('data-caption'` That's why your code fails.

Comment: @user3860465 There is anothe problem was with your selector too

Comment: @user3860465 If you feel anyone of the answers provided here satisfied your need, then try to click on the tick mark available with that answer in order to show your acceptance to the future visitors.. And it is not a compulsion... :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong selector, Your current selector will chek for the anchor inside the class `fancybox` .So change the code like this,

```
 $("#btnchange").click(function () {
      $("a.fancybox").attr("data-caption", "i am new caption");

 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RyTcS/408/)

Comment: attr not working ...as per the answers we can see ..it is 'data'

Comment: @user3860465 "attr not working". How can you say that its not working? Its working fine.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi : what the OP means is that you could use the `attr()` method to set a **new** `data-caption` attribute but **NOT** to change an existing one. If the second, you should rather use the `.data(key,value)` format as suggested by Raja http://jsfiddle.net/9Wwyt/

Comment: @JFK Can you check this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/9Wwyt/1/. Here the value is changing by using .attr() method

Comment: @AnoopJoshi : well, you are right, it does change. However, the issue is that fancybox's `title` doesn't get it unless you use `.data(key, value)`. Here an interesting discussion about the subject http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262427/1055987

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnchange', function() {
    $('a.fancybox').data('caption', 'i am new caption');
});
```

[**You might find this example useful**](http://jsfiddle.net/cq4P9/)